# C++: implementation of a class methods in a separated shared library

Tags: c++, class, implementation, dlopen

I figure out I can have the implementation of parts of a class in a shared lib, as far as the symbols are loaded when used.

```
myclass.h
---

class C {
void method();
}

main.cpp
---

#include "myclass.h"
int main() {
    //dynamically load mylib.so using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose
        ...
    C *c = new C();
    c->method();
    delete c;
}

mylib.so compiled separately:
====
mylib.cpp
---

#include "mylib.h"
void C::method() {
...
}
```

This works fine.

However once I finished using C::method(), I would like to unload it, so I can change, recompile and reload it without having to restart the main program

```
int main() {
    //dynamically load mylib.so using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose
        ...
    C *c = new C();
    c->method();
    delete c;
    // close the lib, remove the handle...
         ....
    char pause;
    cin << pause; // before carrying on change the C::method, recompile it

    //dynamically load *Again* mylib.so using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose
        ...
    C *c = new C();
    c->method();
    delete c; 
}
```

The problem is that it does not unload the library when doing the first dlclose, probably because an instance of my class C exists.
Any way to force this?

(using g++ 4.2.3, on Linux Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: I don't think it is tracked that you have an instance of a class (especially by pointer). How do you know, library is not unloaded?

Comment: Can you call `dlerror` after `dlclose` to see why the library wasn't unloaded ?

Comment: @Krizz: the behavior remains the same despites the changes I do. E.g. cout <<"changes made" << endl won't be displayed.
Also strace points out the library being opened only once.
27732 open("[...]ReloadablePart.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
...
27732 close(4)                          = 0
27732 write(1, "Calling reloadedPart...\n", 24) = 24
Btw, I do not really understand the "close(...) =0" information ; if the lib is unloaded, why can I call the symbols of it after?

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: no error displayed after "cout << dlerror() << endl", however doing so will prevent my application from displaying any output

Comment: Are you opening the library with `RTLD_GLOBAL`? That might cause other libraries to use symbols within it, preventing it from unloading when closed. If you just want to find symbols with `dlsym` then you don't need that flag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Short Answer

It won't work the way you are doing it. There might also be other problems with your approach that haven't bitten you yet.

#### Why it doesn't work

Undefined symbols in your program/library are resolved at different times. On most systems, data references (global variables, class vtables, etc.) are always resolved when your program/library is loaded. Code references are resolved when they are first used on some systems ("lazy lookup"; it happens on Linux and Mac OS X, at least), unless some special options are set (RTLD_NOW parameter for dlopen or LD_BIND_NOW environment variable). Once these are resolved, no new lookup will take place.

If you `dlopen` your library with the RTLD_GLOBAL flag before the lazy lookup for a method is done, the method from your library will be used. The code reference to the method is now resolved; it won't change again. Your main program now officially uses symbols from your `dlopen`ed library, so `dlclose` will no longer close the library - `dlclose` only drops your explicit handle to it.

In short, you should only ever expect to unload libraries that you only use via explicit calls to `dlsym`.

#### What to do instead

What you *can* do instead is have your library provide a derived class implementation. You'd define your class `C` as an abstract base class:

```
class C
{
public:
    virtual void method();
    virtual ~C();
};
```

In your separately-compiled library, you'd define a derived class and a function that creates an object of that derived class:

```
class D : public C
{
public:
    virtual void method();
};

void D::method()
{
    // ...
}

extern "C" C* createC()
{
    return new D();
}
```

Now, in your main program, you'd load the library using `dlopen`, get a function pointer to `createD` using `dlsym` and call it to get an object. When all objects are gone, you can call `dlclose`, recompile your library, and do the whole thing again:

```
typedef C* (*creatorFunction)();

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        void *handle = dlopen("mylib.so", 0);
        creatorFunction create = (creatorFunction) dlsym(handle, "createC");

        C *c = (*create)();
        c->method();
        delete c;

        dlclose(handle);

        char pause;
        cin << pause;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this different? The `createC()` function could move between library loads, right?

Comment: @AndresJaanTack Yes, but more importantly: In the original code, the c->method() line is a direct function call to the library, which causes a lazy symbol lookup. Once the lazy symbol lookup has happened, C::method() always refers to that code, and the library cannot be unloaded any more. Here, there are no direct calls; (*create)() goes via a function pointer obtained from dlsym, and c->method() is a virtual function call, so ``dlclose`` will still unload the library.

Comment: @wolfgang: great explanation. And that looks better design to not split the code of an object in separated files. However it would have been convenient in some testing cases, and it seams it is "only" because of "once The code reference to the method is resolved, it won't change again". I am not going to test it out, but if there is a way to undo that, that would make this split of declaration and implementation possible.

Comment: it seems that "delete c" will cause undefined behavior in my test, since C is the base class which points to the child instance. could someone tell the correct way to delete the child object ?

Comment: @Dreaminthewind
Yes, to be entirely correct, you need to declare the a virtual destructor; I've edited my answer to add that one `virtual ~C()` line.