# C++: class in dynamic .so library

Tags: c++, class, dynamic

So, i have really huge problem lately. In my project for work I receive a json file and in there will be name off library with implementation of some equations. And my boss wants that in .so file must be class not some procedure. So i write the code according to this [C++: implementation of a class methods in a separated shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806630/c-implementation-of-a-class-methods-in-a-separated-shared-library)

```
Stress.h

    #ifndef STRESS_H
    #define STRESS_H

    #include "Model.h"

    class Stress{
    public:
        virtual double calc(model, double, double, double);
    };

    #endif  /* STRESS_H */
```

and .cpp file

```
Stress.cpp

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Model.h"
#include "Stress.h"

class Hans_S : public Stress
{
public:
    model m;
    double Temperature;
    double E;
    double Edot;
    virtual double calc(model, double, double, double);
};

double Hans_S::calc(model m, double E, double Edot, double T)
{
    double s;

    s = m.params[0] * pow(E,m.params[1]) * exp(((-(m.params[2]))*E)) * pow((Edot),m.params[3]) * exp(((-(m.params[4])) * (T/1000))); 

    return s*pow(10,6);
}

extern "C" Stress* create()
{
    return new Hans_S();
}
```

And when i compile the .cpp file like this

```
g++ -fPIC -shared Stress.cpp -o Stress.so
```

I got this error

```
Stress.cpp:25:12: error: ‘Stress’ does not name a type
 extern "C" Stress* create()
            ^
```

I would be gratefull if someone coudl tell me where i made a mistake.. When i was using just procedure like extern "c" double calc etc. it works correctly but when i rewrite to class it's just punch me in the face...

and Model.h looks like this

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H

using namespace std;
enum Model_type
{
    Stress = 0,
    Strain,
    S_recrystalization,
    D_recrystalization,
    G_growth
};
struct model
{
    string name;
        Model_type type;        
    double *params;
};

#endif  /* MODEL_H */
```

Comment: Why `extern "C"` actually, and not just `extern` if you have pure c++ everywhere? Also besides providing a singleton shared global, having a static factory API might be the better choice, to get instances from shared libraries.

Comment: i use `extern "C"` according to that link, so when i used dlopen in code i can find proper name, if i remember correctly c++ is adding random chars to functions name. Am i right? btw sorry for bad english... it's just from like 60 hours classes and games...

Comment: 'extern "C"' but returning a 'class Stress*'? Sounds strange to me. Did you try putting "class" before "Stress*"?

Comment: Keltar has spotted what I think is the main problem, I would also follow the advice of thi gg

I am still a bit confused on what exactly you are trying to achieve and this question feels more like a code review/fix

I would highly recommend taking a step back, possibly reading:

http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

and asking a more specific question like "how to wrap json in an .so with a C++ interface"

Comment: Also this kind of sounds like node.js in reverse..you sure you got the brief right? I just don't want you going down the wrong path if the deadline is really that tight

http://www.benfarrell.com/2013/01/03/c-and-node-js-an-unholy-combination-but-oh-so-right/

Comment: @chrispepper1989 question maybe is a little messy cause my lack of english ;) the main problem is that the stress is equation of material property and it consider it's durability. I write a program that allow you to change my model of durability (change the equation) and replace by yours model. To do that my program gets from webGUI a json file with name of model (also name of library) so i can call method from .so

Hope that you understand the idea now ;) this resolve rewriting the code to add one more model :)

Comment: So you have a client program that gets models from a server?

And the client program is C++ and the server is javascript? 

I still don't fully understand the reason for the Json files, unless this is a feature outside of your control?

I understand the problem, I just don't understand why the current solution is so complex.

Comment: My program is a simulation module that can compute temperatures, strains, stress, microstructure of hot metal rolling operation. This requires super powerfull computers so my code is running on sth like cloud. It's a lot of cores together etc. And this code will be run from browser, so but user has to set a lot of parameters for hot rolling mill and we need to exchange info. Some default info will be kept on database but user has to set it up. When user wants to change model he will add to binaries and send to GRID where my program launch proper .so lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stress is not pure virtual and there is no implementation for it.

```
 virtual double calc(model, double, double, double) = 0;
```

Would make it pure virtual. That is the reason why the compiler says Stress does not name a type, because the class is incomplete.

If you look at this example: http://ideone.com/TpwcZa you can see, that it compiles only if you add the =0.

(working code here: http://ideone.com/K5zdDy)

According to Keltar: you can resolve the name conflict with the enum in 2 ways:

- rename it
- make it an `enum class` which has its own namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Your class named 'Stress', but your `enum Model_type` also have 'Stress' variant. You should either remove this conflict, or add `class` specifier: `extern "C" class Stress* create()`.